ggplot2 adds a second image title on the right side
While reproducing an images using ggplot2, there was an interesting requirement. Add a second title to the figure, set the location to the right (it would be nice to make changes to the color and other features). It looks like this:

Using the annotate function, this approach is not very convenient due to the limitations of panel.
After searching, the following provides a way to do this:
Add ggplot annotation outside the panel? Or two titles?
I wonder if there is now a simpler and more direct way to accomplish this.
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle('left')+
  annotate("text", label="right", 
           x=Inf, y=Inf, vjust=1, hjust=1)



One of the recent additions to ggplot since v3.5.1 is the ability to specify x and y co-ordinates of text annotations in npc co-ordinates (i.e. relative to the panel, where the bottom left corner is at x = 0, y = 0, and the top right is x = 1, y = 1). The way to do this is to wrap the desired x and y co-ordinates in I().
This makes it easy to place text at a fixed position outside the plotting panel as long as we turn clipping off:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  ggtitle('left') +
  annotate("text", label = "right", x = I(1), y = I(1), hjust = 1,
           vjust = -1, size = 8) +
  theme_gray(20)



Elegant solution! Thank you for your reply. Your reply also does a good job of showing subsequent readers the direction of a similar operation. (Which was also the original purpose of this question)

Nice solution !

This method has a little problem when I plot the map and add the parameter default_crs in the coords_sf function ...... Once default_crs is set, the annotate position is not correct. Do you think this is a bug or something else? For example:
ne_countries(continent = "africa") |>
st_crs()
ggplot()+
geom_sf()+
ggtitle('left')+
annotate("text", label = "right", x = I(1), y = I(1), hjust = 1,
vjust = -1, size = 4) +
coord_sf(crs ="+proj=laea +y_0=0 +lon_0=155 +lat_0=-90 +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs",
# default_crs = st_crs(4326),
clip = "off")

I don't know of any easier option to add a "second" title. But besides the option to manipulate the gtable (which I think is the cleanest approach), you might consider using annotation_custom which however requires to properly account for the specs of the title. Note that for simplicity I set vjust=0 to vertically align both titles (Using the default vjust=1 I wasn't able to figure out how to achieve that.):
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "left") +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::textGrob(
      label = "right",
      x = unit(1, "npc"),
      y = unit(1, "npc") +
        # Account for default theme_grey bottom margin of the title
        unit(5.5, "pt"),
      vjust = 0, hjust = 1,
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = "red",
        # Default theme_grey Title font size = rel(1.2)
        fontsize = 11 * 1.2
      )
    )
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 0))



This has become easier to do since v3.5.1. We can now use npc co-ordinates inside annotate by wrapping in I()

Thank you for your reply. This is indeed a solution！
